# Send gcloud build result to pubsub

Tags: gcloud

I want to send the cloud build result to a gcloud pubsub after the build. This is required because I want to add the build successful condition to all my PRs inside bitbucket.

Somehow I am either to stupid to find a propper documentation about how to add this pubsub step in the cloudbuild.yaml or there is not enough information out there.

Can anyone help here?

Post-build step, waitFor step. However gcloud build does not seem to support those actions.

Comment: Hi Mauro Bono, did you see my answer below? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a pubsub topic named `cloud-builds` a message is sent to it whenever a builds status changes.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications

If you have other needs you could use the `gcloud` CLI in your build with the help of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker

PS: check out https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-notifiers if you want to filter the pubsub messages inside gcp and trigger a webhook instead.